# Mediplayer android not playing http stream

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

So here is my alaram receive, it works when the app is killed no problem, notification is fired and everything seems fine.

```
public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
        private CharSequence msg = "Notofication";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("Alarm reciever", "Reached");
        String sationSelected = intent.getStringExtra("SationSelected");
        Log.i("slected is :", sationSelected);
        Intent serviceRadio = new Intent(context, RadioService.class);
        serviceRadio.putExtra("SationSelected",sationSelected);
        context.startService(serviceRadio);
        Intent dismissIntent = new Intent(context,DismissBroadcast.class);
        dismissIntent.putExtra("Notification ID",1);
        PendingIntent piDismiss = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 100, dismissIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setOngoing(true)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle("Radio station playing")
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setContentText("Radio station playing content")
                        .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                .bigText(msg))
                        .addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round,
                                "Stop Radio", piDismiss);


        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(1, builder.build());
        Log.e("You are at the","Receiver");
    }
}
```

Here is my service, I removed some of the stations but left some to give you an idea what i am doing, when the app is killed this service does not seem to load the URL. If app is not killed then this service works fine.

```
 public class RadioService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {
        MediaPlayer myPlayer;
        Context context = this;
    //// creat sation link variable////////////
        String LBC = "http://media-ice.musicradio.com/LBCUKMP3Low";
        String BBCRadio1 = "http://bbcmedia.ic.llnwd.net/stream/bbcmedia_radio1_mf_p";
        String Kiss = "http://icy-e-ba-01-gos.sharp-stream.com/kissnational.aac";
        String AbsoluteRadio = "http://mp3-ar-128.timlradio.co.uk/Title1=Absolute Radio 1215AM, Discover Real Music (High Quality) Length1=-1Version=2";
        String AbsoluteClassicRock = "http://mp3-ac-32.timlradio.co.uk/Title1=Absolute Classic Rock - Home of the Great British Guarantee (Standard Quality) Length1=-1Version=2";
        String Absolute80s = "http://mp3-a8-32.timlradio.co.uk/Title1=Absolute 80s (Standard Quality) Length1=-1Version=2";
        String AbsoluteRadio60s = "http://mp3-a6-32.timlradio.co.uk/Title1=Absolute Radio 60s (Standard Quality) Length1=-1Version=2";
        String AbsoluteRadio70s = "http://mp3-a7-32.timlradio.co.uk/Title1=Absolute Radio 70s (Standard Quality) Length1=-1Version=2";
        String AbsoluteRadio90s = "http://mp3-a9-32.timlradio.co.uk/Title1=Absolute Radio 90s (Standard Quality) Length1=-1Version=2";
        String AbsoluteRadio00s = "http://mp3-a0-32.timlradio.co.uk/Title1=Absolute Radio 00s (Standard Quality) Length1=-1Version=2";
        String BBCRadio1xtra = "http://bbcmedia.ic.llnwd.net/stream/bbcmedia_radio1xtra_mf_p";
        String BBCRadio2 = "http://bbcmedia.ic.llnwd.net/stream/bbcmedia_radio2_mf_p";
        String BBCRadio3 = "http://bbcmedia.ic.llnwd.net/stream/bbcmedia_radio3_mf_p";
        String BBCRadio4FM = "http://bbcmedia.ic.llnwd.net/stream/bbcmedia_radio4fm_mf_p";
        String BBCRadio4Extra = "http://bbcmedia.ic.llnwd.net/stream/bbcmedia_radio4extra_mf_p";
        String BBCRadio5Live = "http://bbcmedia.ic.llnwd.net/stream/bbcmedia_radio5live_mf_p";
        String BBCRadio5LiveSportsballExtra = "http://bbcmedia.ic.llnwd.net/stream/bbcmedia_radio5extra_mf_p";
        String BBCRadio6Music = "http://bbcmedia.ic.llnwd.net/stream/bbcmedia_6music_mf_p";
        String BBCAsianNetwork = "http://bbcmedia.ic.llnwd.net/stream/bbcmedia_asianet_mf_p";

        ArrayList<String> stationList = new ArrayList<>();

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }

        //WifiManager.WifiLock wifiLock = ((WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE)).createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL,"MyLockWIFI");
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            //WifiManager.WifiLock wifiLock = ((WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE))
              //      .createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL, "mylock");
            PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
            PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,"partialWakrLock");
            wakeLock.acquire();


            Log.i("stt comand Radio recier","True");
            ///// get station selected////////////////////////////
            String selectedStation = intent.getStringExtra("SationSelected");
            Log.i("INtent selected = ",selectedStation);
            //////// create new media player
                myPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                //wifiLock.acquire();
                myPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(),PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
                myPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            mp.start();
                    }
                });
                myPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            //// Pass the selected sation to set stream///////////
                try {
                    stationList.add("0");
                    stationList.add(LBC);
                    stationList.add(BBCRadio1);
                    stationList.add(AbsoluteRadio);
                    stationList.add(AbsoluteClassicRock);
                    stationList.add(Absolute80s);
                    stationList.add(AbsoluteRadio60s);
                    stationList.add(AbsoluteRadio70s);
                    stationList.add(AbsoluteRadio90s);
                    stationList.add(AbsoluteRadio00s);
                    stationList.add(BBCRadio1xtra);
                    stationList.add(BBCRadio2);
                    stationList.add(BBCRadio3);
                    stationList.add(BBCRadio4FM);
                    stationList.add(BBCRadio4Extra);
                    stationList.add(BBCRadio5Live);
                    stationList.add(BBCRadio5LiveSportsballExtra);
                    stationList.add(BBCRadio6Music);
                    stationList.add(BBCAsianNetwork);
                    stationList.add(BBCWorldServiceUKstream);
                    stationList.add(BBCWorldServiceNewsstream);
                    stationList.add(ClassicFM);
                    stationList.add(CapitalFM);
                    stationList.add(PlanetRock);
                    stationList.add(JazzFM);
                    stationList.add(RadioX);
                    stationList.add(HeartLondon);
                    stationList.add(SmoothFM);
                    stationList.add(RinseFM);
                    stationList.add(RadioCaroline);
                    String url = null;
                    if(!selectedStation.equals("Random")){
                        if (selectedStation.equals("LBC")) {
                        url = LBC;
                            Log.i("LBC = ", LBC);
                    }else{
                        if(selectedStation.equals("BBC")){
                            url = BBCRadio1;
                            Log.i("BBC = ", BBCRadio1);
                        }else{
                            if(selectedStation.equals("Kiss")){
                                url = Kiss;
                                Log.i("Kiss = ", Kiss);
                            }else{
                                if(selectedStation.equals("AbsoluteRadio")){
                                    url = AbsoluteRadio;
                                }else{
                                    if (selectedStation.equals("AbsoluteClassicRock")){
                                        url = AbsoluteClassicRock;
                                    }else{
                                        if (selectedStation.equals("Absolute 80s")){
                                            url = Absolute80s;
                                        }else{
                                            if (selectedStation.equals("AbsoluteRadio 60s")){
                                                url = AbsoluteRadio60s;
                                            }else{
                                                if (selectedStation.equals("AbsoluteRadio 70s")){
                                                    url = AbsoluteRadio70s;
                                                }else{
                                                    if (selectedStation.equals("AbsoluteRadio 90s")){
                                                        url = AbsoluteRadio90s;
                                                    }else{
                                                        if (selectedStation.equals("AbsoluteRadio 00s")){
                                                            url = AbsoluteRadio00s;
                                                        }else{
                                                            if (selectedStation.equals("BBC Radio 1xtra")){
                                                                url = BBCRadio1xtra;
                                                            }else{
                                                                if (selectedStation.equals("BBC Radio 2")){
                                                                    url = BBCRadio2;
                                                                }else{
                                                                    if (selectedStation.equals("BBC Radio 3")){
                                                                        url = BBCRadio3;
                                                                    }else{
                                                                        if (selectedStation.equals("BBC Radio 4FM")){
                                                                            url = BBCRadio4FM;
                                                                        }else{
                                                                            if (selectedStation.equals("BBC Radio  4Extra")){
                                                                                url = BBCRadio4Extra;
                                                                            }else{
                                                                                if (selectedStation.equals("BBC Radio 5 Live")){
                                                                                    url = BBCRadio5Live;
                                                                                }else{
                                                                                    if (selectedStation.equals("BBC Radio 5 Live Sportsball Extra")){
                                                                                        url = BBCRadio5LiveSportsballExtra;
                                                                                    }else{
                                                                                        if (selectedStation.equals("BBC Radio 6 Music")){
                                                                                            url = BBCRadio6Music;
                                                                                        }else{
                                                                                            if (selectedStation.equals("BBC Asian Network")){
                                                                                                url = BBCAsianNetwork;
                                                                                            }else{
                                                                                                if (selectedStation.equals("BBC World Service UK")){
                                                                                                    url = BBCWorldServiceUKstream;
                                                                                                }else{
                                                                                                    if (selectedStation.equals("BBC World Service News")){
                                                                                                        url = BBCWorldServiceNewsstream;
                                                                                                    }else{
                                                                                                        if (selectedStation.equals("Classic FM")){
                                                                                                            url = ClassicFM;
                                                                                                        }else{
                                                                                                            if (selectedStation.equals("Capital FM")){
                                                                                                                url = CapitalFM;
                                                                                                            }else{
                                                                                                                if (selectedStation.equals("Planet Rock")){
                                                                                                                    url = PlanetRock;
                                                                                                                }else{
                                                                                                                    if (selectedStation.equals("Jazz FM")){
                                                                                                                        url = JazzFM;
                                                                                                                    }else{
                                                                                                                        if (selectedStation.equals("Radio X")){
                                                                                                                            url = RadioX;
                                                                                                                        }else{
                                                                                                                            if (selectedStation.equals("Heart London")){
                                                                                                                                url = HeartLondon;
                                                                                                                            }else{
                                                                                                                                if (selectedStation.equals("Smooth FM")){
                                                                                                                                    url = SmoothFM;
                                                                                                                                }else{
                                                                                                                                    if (selectedStation.equals("Rinse FM")){
                                                                                                                                        url = RinseFM;
                                                                                                                                    }else{
                                                                                                                                        if (selectedStation.equals("Radio Caroline")){
                                                                                                                                            url = RadioCaroline;
                                                                                                                                        }else{
                                                                                                                                            if (selectedStation.equals("The Breeze Radio")){
                                                                                                                                                url = TheBreezeRadio;
                                                                                                                                            }else{
                                                                                                                                                if (selectedStation.equals("Image FM")){
                                                                                                                                                    url = ImageFM;
                                                                                                                                                }else{
                                                                                                                                                    if (selectedStation.equals("Max Radio")){
                                                                                                                                                        url = MaxRadio;
                                                                                                                                                    }else{
                                                                                                                                                        if (selectedStation.equals("Kane FM")){
                                                                                                                                                            url = KaneFM;
                                                                                                                                                        }else{
                                                                                                                                                            if (selectedStation.equals("Sunshine Radio")){
                                                                                                                                                                url = SunshineRadio;
                                                                                                                                                            }else{
                                                                                                                                                                if (selectedStation.equals("Talk Sport")){
                                                                                                                                                                    url = TalkSport;
                                                                                                                                                                }else{
                                                                                                                                                                    if (selectedStation.equals("Capital Extra")){
                                                                                                                                                                        url = CapitalExtra;
                                                                                                                                                                    }else{
                                                                                                                                                                        if (selectedStation.equals("Magic")){
                                                                                                                                                                            url = Magic;
                                                                                                                                                                        }
                                                                                                                                                                    }
                                                                                                                                                                }
                                                                                                                                                            }
                                                                                                                                                        }
                                                                                                                                                    }
                                                                                                                                                }
                                                                                                                                            }
                                                                                                                                        }
                                                                                                                                    }
                                                                                                                                }
                                                                                                                            }
                                                                                                                        }
                                                                                                                    }
                                                                                                                }
                                                                                                            }
                                                                                                        }
                                                                                                    }
                                                                                                }
                                                                                            }
                                                                                        }
                                                                                    }
                                                                                }
                                                                            }
                                                                        }
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    myPlayer.setDataSource(url);
                    }else{
                        Random r = new Random();
                        int s = r.nextInt(stationList.size() - 1) + 1;
                        Log.i("S station = ", stationList.get(s));
                        myPlayer.setDataSource(stationList.get(s));
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //Set volume to max
            AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                    audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC),flags);
            // Prepare myPlayer
                myPlayer.prepareAsync();
            Log.i("Check Wake lock = ", String.valueOf(wakeLock.isHeld()));
            wakeLock.release();
            //wifiLock.release();
            return START_STICKY;

        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

            //Start myPlayer
            mp.start();
        }
        public void onDestroy(){
            //Stop and tidy up myPlayer
            myPlayer.stop();
            myPlayer.release();
            myPlayer = null;
            super.onDestroy();
        }
        /////////

    }
```

and my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.radioalarm">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:process=":remote" android:name=".AlarmReciever"/>
        <receiver android:name=".OnBootReciever">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name=".DismissBroadcast" />
        <service android:name=".OnBootService"
            android:enabled="true"/>
        <service android:name=".RadioService"
            android:enabled="true">
        </service>

        <activity android:name=".SavedAlarms" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. To play stream with Media Player Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895409/android-media-player-play-from-network-stream). Utilize this inside service

> My hunch is that my service is not being called.

2. Check that service is declared in manifest and your your service class is extended from Service not IntentService 
   if Service is properly declared inside AndroidManifest.xml and started from a valid context service will run properly
   Override `onStop()` and `onDestroye()` put log and then check your log
   also add log inside `onStartCommand`

> I have implemented a wake lock in my service but still no joy.
>   I have also implemented a wake lock for the media player its self and
>   still no joy.

no need to implement wake lock, as long as service is running the music will play

Also you can study this [GoogleProject](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/RandomMusicPlayer) for music player.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have services implemented as you have said already and everthing is present in the manifest. Everything runs fine and my logs are showing correctly when the phone is connected to the computer via usb. I am debugging in android studio. I suppose i mean to ask, why would it work normally when connected to the computer as oppsed to when not connected?

Comment: I have refined the problem. One was that some of my streaming sources where not working properly so thats fine. The issue is now the service does not run if the app is dead. Ignore my whole usb question :/. How do i get my service to run if app is not active ?

Comment: Which device are you using?

Comment: If you are using an Huawei device, goto Setting and find Protected Apps,

Comment: You must check your app as protected app in huawei device. then when you kill your app the service will be restarted again

Comment: I am using a android samsung s7 device. When alarm manager fires i have a intent that starts my service in my on recieve method. The trouble is that the user will set an alarm and close the app and when this happens the on recieve still works but the service is not called. How do i start a service if the app is dead?

Comment: when an alarm is fired your app is not dead, post your code here so that we can understand more, Manifest, Alarm, Service

Comment: Ok, i am currently at work and have commitments this evening, i will post it on saturday. Thanks again for your help.